# C# Map network drive via CMD

Tags: c#, cmd, network-drive

The user can choose the drive letter from a combobox and they do not have to type the server name only the last part to a textbox and if they finished they just have to click on a button. The only problem is CMD window pop up, but the code wont run, not even a error message like the path wasn't correct etc. What's the mistake?

```
    private void MapBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string PathValue = Path.Text;
        string DriveValue = Drive.SelectedText;
        Process map = new Process();
        map.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        map.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        map.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        map.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c net use "+DriveValue + @"\\servername\"+PathValue +"/persistent:Yes";
        map.Start();
    }
```

Comment: What is the obsession people have with cmd.exe? Why not run `net` directly (with `UseShellExecute = true`)?

Comment: ... or use the respective PowerShell commandlet in [Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0)?

Comment: I don't understand like John why a C# programmer wants to run `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` to run `%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe` to use functions in `mpr.dll` which could be used directly in C# coded application as well. `net.exe` uses from `mpr.dll` the functions `WNetGetConnectionW`, `WNetEnumResourceW`, `WNetAddConnection2W`, `WNetCancelConnection2W`, `WNetOpenEnumW`, `WNetGetLastErrorW`, `WNetCloseEnum`.

Comment: They are all documented by Microsoft on the pages [winnetwk.h header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnetwk/) and [Using Windows Networking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wnet/using-windows-networking). A C# coded application needs to run __never__ `cmd.exe` or `powershell.exe` because of these executables use just functions in Windows libraries which a C# coded application can use directly, too.